# Simple Tree Insert Node Function turning up Null

Tags: c++, tree

I have implemented this Simple Tree, yet I keep getting NULL values when trying to insert after my rootNode. The debugger shows that my mValue is NULL. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I can't seem to figure it out after looking around.

```
class Tree {
public:

    Tree()
    {
    mRootNode = NULL;
    }

    ~Tree()
    {
        if (mRootNode != NULL)
        {
            delete mRootNode;
        }
    }

    void PushValues(int value)
    {
        if (mRootNode == NULL)
        {
            mRootNode = new TreeNode(value);
        }
        else
        {
            mRootNode->PushNodeValues(value);
        }
    }

    void PrintValues()
    {
        if (mRootNode == NULL)
        {
            mRootNode->PrintNodeValues();
        }
    }



private:


    class TreeNode
    {
        TreeNode* mLeft;
        TreeNode* mRight;
        int mValue;
    public:

        TreeNode(int value)
        {

            std::cout << "you are inside the treenode constuctor" << std::endl;
            mValue = value;
            //mLeft = NULL; 
            //mRight = NULL;
        }
        ~TreeNode()
        {
            if (mLeft != NULL)
            {
                delete mLeft;
            }

            if (mRight != NULL)
            {
                delete mRight;
            }


        }
        void PushNodeValues(int value)
        {


            if (value < mValue)
            {
                if (mLeft = NULL)
                {
                    mLeft = new TreeNode(value);
                }

                else
                {
                    mLeft->PushNodeValues(value);
                }
            }

            else
            {
                if (mRight == NULL)
                {
                    mRight = new TreeNode(value);
                }
                else
                {
                    mRight->PushNodeValues(value);
                }
            }
        }

        void printnodeValue()
        {
            std::cout << "value is " << mValue << std::endl;
        }
        void PrintNodeValues()
        {
            if (mLeft != NULL)
            mLeft->PrintNodeValues();
             printf("%d, ", mValue);


            if (mRight != NULL)
            mRight->PrintNodeValues(); 
            printf("%d, ", mValue); 
        }

    };

    TreeNode* mRootNode;

};


int main()
{

    int data[] = {
        60, 36, 25, 44, 62, 58, 25, 66, 84, 48,
        1, 63, 6, 58, 40, 73, 30, 100, 88, 60,
        100, 73, 77, 55, 6, 33, 69, 4, 93, 33,
        36, 53, 79, 2, 35, 41, 64, 76, 70, 81,
        55, 22, 20, 44, 93, 58, 14, 6, 60, 36
    };


    Tree myTree;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {

        myTree.PushValues(data[i]);
    }


    myTree.PrintValues(); 

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: It's more like a link list with misguiding structure than a tree. Try explaining your work first.

Comment: Well I am inserting this group on integers into this simple intrusive tree. When i push my first integer into the tree it creates a new node and I can check the the Tree's rootnode member variable and see that 60 is inside. 
When i insert the second integer, PushValues() notices that my rootnode is not null, so it calls InsertNodeValue on the rootNode.  But when it goes that function its says mValue is NULL, but shouldn't is be equal to value of the rootNode since thats what the node calling the function?

Comment: Please help. I've been stuck for a while pulling my hairs out!!

Comment: This will **never** be true: `if (mLeft = NULL)` - that's an assignment, not a test for equivalence. Turn up your compiler warnings and treat them as errors.

Comment: Didn't notice that thank you, but my code breaks before that. Any idea why its not reading the value of mrootNode to compare with the current value?

Comment: You need to initialize ALL you node members on construction. Why did you comment out the nullifying of left and right pointers? And this: `if (mRootNode == NULL)` makes zero sense to use as the test for *true* before printing values. It should be checked for non-null, not null. A debugger works *wonders* for finding runtime problems. Take the time to learn to use one.

Comment: I was just running different test to try to identify the problem. But even when I do initialize left and right to NULL. I cannot get past inserting the RootNode value.

Comment: Fix the problems I noted and I beg to differ. It will run. [See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a2adeb24a432ca91).

Comment: Sorry, but I simply don't believe that. I applied the changes stated, compiled the program, and ran it. [The link in my prior comment shows this, and *it runs*.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a2adeb24a432ca91). If you don't have C++11 you may have to change the `nullptr` to `NULL` in that code, but it *will* run.

Comment: Replace the assignment with comparison as instructed. Uncomment both initializations to NULL. I just tested it with no problems.

Comment: Than you WhozCraig I got it!!!!! Also forgot to remove second printf statement. It printed out certain nodes multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in your Tree Structure, here is a sample code on how you should be securing your data in tree recursively.

> Note: This is just a basic structure of insert function that I modified
>   for you from your given code. You still have to add exceptions and stuff.

```
TreeNode* PushValues(TreeNode*& node,int key)
{
    if (node == NULL)
    {
        TreeNode *newNode = new TreeNode(key);
        return newNode;
    }
    if (key < node->mValue)
        node->mLeft = PushValues(node->mLeft, key);
    else if (key > node->mValue)
        node->mRight = PushValues(node->mRight, key);
    return node;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man this works as well, but my situation required me to implement  a push value functions without pushing a node as a parameter!

Comment: @Skazi that yourself that you did it right, because this code is wrong. `root = new TreeNode(value);` allocates a node, saves the pointer to a local automatic variable `root`, then promptly loses it once `root` falls out of scope. To have made this "work" would require `root` be passed by *reference* (a reference to a pointer). As written `PushValues(mRootNode, value);` will allocate a node, leak it, and leave `mRootNode` completely unchanged.

Comment: @WhozCraig I  told him that it's just a **Basic Structure** on how he should be traversing the tree, man he should brain storm all these things by himself.

Comment: Edited @WhozCraig